# Paste Text from Android Emulator Clipboard to PC

Tags: android, emulation, clipboard, seetest, experitest

I'm a new user at experitest. So far no problem with the activity of pasting text from my desktop PC to Android emulator. Well, now, I want to do the opposite. So please tell me how do I paste text from android emulator clipboard to my desktop PC notepad?.

Answer (score 0):

If you long press your left mouse (for like 2 seconds) on your text in the emulator, the options to copy/paste will appear. If you copy your text, you are also able to paste it to your pc.

If you want to copy from your clipboard directly. I think that is not possible, because it only provides the paste option. So you could only paste the text from your clipboard in your emulator and copy it from there to your pc.

Edit:

Try to Cold Boot the emulator.

1. Go to Device Manager
   [image: Device Manager]
2. Click on the 3 dot icon and select 'Cold Boot Now' for the emulator you want to use
   [image: Cold Boot]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still unable to do it: https://s1.gifyu.com/images/ttttttttt.gif

Comment: Hm, that's weird. You could try to cold boot your emulator. Go to Device Manager -> click the 3 dots on from the device you want to use -> click 'Cold Boot Now'

Comment: There's NO such an option on the seetest cloud: https://s1.gifyu.com/images/see.gif ...can you please make a short gif tuts for this?. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer on how to cold boot the emulator.

Comment: Hi Lucas. You didn't read my question carefully. So, I'm talking about android emulator on https://cloud.seetest.io, and not on AVD Manager. Btw, thank you so much attention.

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry...I unfortunately overlooked that. I haven't used these emulators, so sadly I'm not able to help you. Sorry